# NLog UI webpage to see logs

Tags: c#, logs, user-interface

I have implemented NLog with database target (SQL Server) but I want to see those log entries in a nice UI.

I have seen these tools on NLog official website

> **NLog-specific viewers**
>
> - Gibraltar (using Gibraltar Adapter for NLog) -
>     https://nlog-project.org/2009/11/01/gibraltar-adapter-for-nlog-released.html
> - Sentinel - https://github.com/yarseyah/sentinel
> - NLogViewer - http://github.com/jkowalski/NLogViewer (functional, but
>     no longer in development, not recommended)
> - LogEntries - http://www.logentries.com (service for cloud logging,
>     has .net NLog target)
> - Legit Log Viewer - http://www.legitlog.com/ (Although their website
>     is down, it is Free and powerful log viewer.)
> - ReflectInsight Viewer (using the ReflectInsight Extension for NLog) -
>     http://insightextensions.codeplex.com/

But I think they only are Desktop applications. I need a web application but I can´t waste time making my own UI because it's already implemented as a class library.

There is also Azure Application Insights but it's paid and you need access to Azure Portal to see it.

Do you know another web UI to integrate with NLog? (free, if it's possible)

EDIT: I'd been using Elmah before I changed to NLog. I need something similar to Elmah's UI

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://github.com/dojo90/NLogViewer

I have also planed a webinterface to easily inject it on ASP .NET Applications.